# Installing WSO2 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS get java_home error

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, path, wso2

Hi I want to install WSO2 API Manager on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I install Java using `sudo apt-get install jre-default` but I got OpenJDK version that isn't recommended for WSO2.

So I proceeded to add oracle repository and install java 8, then I configured as default java version and used the `source /etc/environment` for update paths, then with `echo $JAVA_HOME` I got this route `/usr/lib/java/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java` and when I run the `wso2server.sh` I got `"Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. Carbon cannot execute java"`

I don't know what is the problem when I installing WSO2 API Manager. Or in the route, also I check the route with Whereis java.

Comment: Can you try to unset it and rest back?

Comment: sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle ./wso2server.sh I solve using this line, thanks